# gnuplot: filter by date without xdata beeing time

Tags: time, gnuplot

I have searched quite some time to resolve the following problem with gnuplot, but I could not find any helpful info. I hope somebody can help me:

I have data showing what percentage a user achieved at a certain date, like:

```
DATE;USERID;PERCENTAGE
2012-03-14;1;92.14
2012-03-13;2;93.55
2012-04-14;1;97.14
2012-04-13;2;83.55
2012-05-14;1;94.14
2012-05-13;1;95.55
```

I want to plot achieved percentage per user let's say from april 2012 onwards (the plot works fine for all dates).

I cannot use

```
set xdata time
```

as the x axis should contain userId. Unfortunately, also the following failed:

```
set datafile separator ";"
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
plot bla.csv using 2:(timecolumn(1) > 2012-05-01 ? $3 : 1/0)
```

leading to the warning "Bad time format in string" and no filtering at all.

I am stuck with this since hours and can't find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `timecolumn` in the `using` statement the corresponding value is given in seconds. Therefore, the timestamp read from the data file is compared with 2012, which is the numeric value extracted from your expression.

Use `strptime` to format the comparison date:

```
set datafile separator ";"
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
set timefmt fmt
plot 'bla.csv' using 2:(timecolumn(1) > strptime(fmt, "2012-05-01") ? $3 : 1/0)
```

Comment: thank you so much, tried it with strptime and it works fine! Best, alexander